# How to add back and next button for CardLayout?

Tags: java, swing, awt, cardlayout

I want to add a 'back' and 'next' button for my gui but it doesn't seem to work. It feels like I'm missing something important in my code. I tried using `cl.next(ImagePanel);` but the method is not working for some reason.

```java
private void initComponents() {
        mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        cardLayout = new java.awt.CardLayout(); 
        imagePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel(cardLayout);
        JLabel firstPicture = new JLabel("");
        JLabel secondPicture = new JLabel("");
        jButton back = new jButton("\u22b2Back");
        jButton next = new jButton("Next\u22b3");

        firstPicture.setIcon(...);
        secondPicture.setIcon(...); 

        imagePanel.add(firstPicture, "1");
        imagePanel.add(secondPicture, "2");
        cardLayout.show(imagePanel, "1"); 

        //...buttons actionPerformed(evt);

        mainPanel.add(imagePanel);
    }

        private void backActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) imagePanel.getLayout();
            cl.previous(imagePanel); //should proceed to the previous image... not working
        }

        private void nextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) imagePanel.getLayout();
            cl.next(imagePanel); //should proceed to the next image... not working

        }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can easier understand where is your problem. Your current code snipplet give us no hint about it. Probably you simply need to revalidate and repaint your `imagePanel`, when you change the selected component (something like `imagePanel.revalidate(); imagePanel.repaint()`).

Comment: Easy answer, but you got help in your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60611409/wrong-parent-for-cardlayout-in-java and it appears you didn't even read the answers (since you haven't yet accepted an answer), so I'll skip this one.

Comment: I tried the `revalidate()` and `repaint()` method but it only works for the button 'next' and does not work for 'back'. It also seems that the `next()` method selects the previous card instead. So I fixed the actionListeners for buttons and reversed the usage of `next()` and `previous()`. It worked.